# How can one calculate this double integral?

Tags: calculus

$$\int_1^\infty \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{m^2+n^2}dmdn$$

I can calculate the first iterated integral but stuck at the second one.

Comment: Looks like a good case for polar coordinates.

Comment: Can you show us your first calculation?

Comment: The second one is just $+\infty$. $f(x)=\frac{\arctan x}{x}$ does not belong to $L^1(1,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{m^2+n^2}\,dm=\frac{\arctan(n)}{n}$$

Inasmuch as $\arctan(n)=\frac{\pi}{2}+O\left(\frac1n\right)$ as $n\to \infty$, the integral

$$\int_1^L \frac{\arctan(n)}{n}\,dn=\frac{\pi}{2}\log(L)+O\left(1\right)\to \infty \,\,\text{as}\,\,L\to \infty$$

Hence the integral of interest fails to converge.

Comment: All that's needed here (+1)

Comment: @rrl Thank you!  Much appreciative.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\frac{1}{m^2+n^2}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}e^{-mx}\,dx \tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dm\,dn}{m^2+n^2}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{Si}(x)\right)e^{-x}\frac{dx}{x}\tag{2}$$
that **is not** a convergent integral, due to the singularity at the origin. On the other hand, integrating along shells it is not difficult to check that
$$ \iint_{\substack{m,n\geq 1 \\ m^2+n^2\leq R^2}}\frac{dm\,dn}{m^2+n^2} \approx C\log R.\tag{3}$$

Comment: [+1] Maybe, it should be said that formula (1) is one of the most classical formulas in Laplace Transform.